# Solve system of ODEs

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of related ordinary differential equations (ODEs) that look like:

> $$C x'(t) + Fx''(t) = 0$$

where $x$ is a $n$-dimensional vector, and $C$ and $F$ are square $n \times n$ matrices.

Assuming reasonable things about $C$ and $F$ (like maybe they're invertible?) is there a closed form solution for $x(t)$ given an initial value for $x(0)$ and $x'(0)$?

I feel fairly comfortable integrating it numerically using something like Runge-Kutta, but I feel like there's probably a closed form solution for at least certain classes of matrices $C$ and $F$.  But it's been too many years since my Differential Equations college course, and I don't really know what to search for.  I know the form above looks remarkably similar to a damped spring ODE, which has a closed form solution involving complex exponents.

Comment: What are the entries of the matrices?

Comment: let $y=x'$, then (assuming $F$ invertible)
$$
Cy+Fy'=0 \implies y'=(-F^{-1}C)y
$$
is linear.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Entries are real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get rid of one of the derivatives by integrating: 
$$
Cx'+Fx''=0 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad Cx(t)+Fx'(t)=A=Cx(0)+Fx'(0)
$$
Then solve with respect to the highest derivative
$$
x'=-(F^{-1}C)x+\big(F^{-1}Cx(0)+x'(0)\big)
$$
Then multiply by $\exp(tF^{-1}C)$ letting $A=F^{-1}Cx(0)+x'(0)$:

$$
\exp(tF^{-1}C)\big(x'+(F^{-1}C)x\big)=\exp(tF^{-1}C)\,A,
$$
or
$$
\big(\exp(tF^{-1}C)x(t)\big)=\exp(tF^{-1}C)\,A.
$$
Finally integrating in $[0,t]$
$$
\exp(tF^{-1}C)x(t)-x(0)=\int_0^t \exp(s\,F^{-1}C)\,A\,ds,
$$
or
\begin{align}
x(t) &=\exp(-tF^{-1}C)x(0)+\int_0^t \exp\big(-(t-s)\,F^{-1}C\big)\,A\,ds \\ &=
\exp(-tF^{-1}C)x(0)+\int_0^t \exp\big(-(t-s)\,F^{-1}C\big)\,\big(F^{-1}Cx(0)+x'(0)\big)\,ds.
\end{align}

Comment: You still have some integrals there, though.  Do I need to numerically integrate them?

Comment: @JayLemmon: Not necessarily - If $A=F^{-1}C$ is invertible, then $\int_0^t\mathrm{e}^{sA}ds=A^{-1}(\mathrm{e}^{tA}-I)$.